# No such Method Exception, in generic method when creating new instances of a class

Tags: java, generics, exception, reflection

I'm reading in a couple of data files with methods like the readWeather method below (third code paragraph). The are two things separating these methods, one are the Class for the data, in the readWeather method the Class is WeatherData.

```
package dev;

public final class GameData {

// code above removed for read-ability

    public final class WeatherData extends Data {
        protected WeatherData(String[] dataLines, int lineIndex) {
            super(dataLines, lineIndex);
        }
    } 
}
```

```
abstract class Data extends Id {

// code above removed for read-ability

   /**
    * Create and read new Data
    * 
    * @param dataLines
    * @param lineIndex
    */
    protected Data(String[] dataLines, int lineIndex) {
        super(createIdentifiableData(dataLines, lineIndex));
        lineIndex += 4;
        dataLinesIndex = readComponentData(dataLines, lineIndex);
    }

    protected Data() {    
        super();
    }
}
```

And the second thing is the HashMap object which is used to store the data in. In this case weatherDataMap.

```
   /**
     * Read data
     * 
     * @param path - datafile
     */
    private void readWeather(String path) {
        setupDataFileInfo(path);
        final int nWeathers = Integer.parseInt(dataLines[lineIndex]);
        weatherDataMap = new HashMap<>(calcHashMapSize(nWeathers));
        for (int i = 0; i < nWeathers; i++) {
            lineIndex++;
            WeatherData data = new WeatherData(dataLines, lineIndex);
            lineIndex = data.getLineIndex();
            weatherDataMap.put(data.getId(), data);
        }
    }
```

Anyway I tried making a generic method in order to stop keeping to make new methods for different kind of data see method below (dataLines is a String[], lineIndex is an int). However I get an java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: dev.GameData$WeatherData.([Ljava.lang.String;, int)

```
     private <T extends Data> HashMap<Integer, T> readData(String className, HashMap<Integer, T> o, String path) {
        setupDataFileInfo(path);
        final int nDatas = Integer.parseInt(dataLines[lineIndex]);
        o = new HashMap<>(calcHashMapSize(nDatas));
        for (int i = 0; i < nDatas; i++) {
            lineIndex++;
            T data;
            try {
                data = (T) Class.forName(className).getDeclaredConstructor(String[].class, int.class)
                        .newInstance(dataLines, lineIndex);
                lineIndex = data.getLineIndex();
                o.put(data.getId(), data);
            } catch (InstantiationException | IllegalAccessException | IllegalArgumentException
                    | InvocationTargetException | NoSuchMethodException | SecurityException
                    | ClassNotFoundException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        return o;
    }
```

This is how a call to the generic readData method would look like.

```
weatherData = readData("dev.GameData$WeatherData", weatherData, "Weather");
```

I also get a "Type safety: Unchecked cast from capture#1-of ? to T" warning on the following line.

```
data = (T) Class.forName(className).getDeclaredConstructor(String[].class, int.class)
                        .newInstance(dataLines, lineIndex);
```

Comment: Do you have to use reflection? Could you use a `BiFunction<String[], Integer, T>` instead?

Comment: @AndyTurner could you provide an short example, I have never used BiFunction and I'm  really not good at functional programming. I found this link which shows simple examples but I have no idea on how to apply that to this case.

Comment: Can you include the code that calls `readData`? It's not clear why this method has to get the class as a `String`. And why do you link to that other question? What do you want to say with that link?

Comment: @Holger I added some clarification. I also removed the link, as the type safety warning was not related to this perhaps.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The class `WeatherData` is an inner class of `GameData`, so an instance of `WeatherData` will always have an associated instance of the outer class. Normally, this reference is initialized automatically when you are calling `new WeatherData(dataLines, lineIndex)` within a non-static method or a constructor of `GameData`, but when accessing it via Reflection, it becomes explicit, so the constructor’s signature is `(GameData,String[],int)` instead of `(String[],int)`. This is equivalent to `someGameData.new WeatherData(dataLines, lineIndex)` on the source code level.

If the `WeatherData` class doesn’t need to access non-static members of `GameData`, just declare it `static`. This solves the `NoSuchMethodException`.

In that case, the simplest fix to the “unchecked cast” warning, with the smallest amount of changes, is to change the `String className` parameter to `Class<T> theClass`.
Then, change `Class.forName(className)` to `theClass`, which will make the unchecked type cast obsolete:

```
private <T extends Data> HashMap<Integer, T> readData(
                         Class<T> theClass, HashMap<Integer, T> o, String path) {
    setupDataFileInfo(path);
    final int nDatas = Integer.parseInt(dataLines[lineIndex]);
    o = new HashMap<>(calcHashMapSize(nDatas));
    for(int i = 0; i < nDatas; i++) {
        lineIndex++;
        T data;
        try {
            data = theClass.getDeclaredConstructor(String[].class, int.class)
                    .newInstance(dataLines, lineIndex);
            lineIndex = data.getLineIndex();
            o.put(data.getId(), data);
        } catch(ReflectiveOperationException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    return o;
}
```

and the caller to

```
weatherData = readData(WeatherData.class, weatherData, "Weather");
```

Note how you gain additional safety. The caller can not pass an arbitrary `String` but only a reference to an existing class fulfilling the `<T extends Data>` constraint.

You can gain even more safety, i.e. regarding the constructor invocation, by using a functional interface to describe the constructor:

```
private <T extends Data> HashMap<Integer, T> readData(
                BiFunction<String[],Integer,T> con, HashMap<Integer, T> o, String path) {
    setupDataFileInfo(path);
    final int nDatas = Integer.parseInt(dataLines[lineIndex]);
    o = new HashMap<>(calcHashMapSize(nDatas));
    for(int i = 0; i < nDatas; i++) {
        lineIndex++;
        T data = con.apply(dataLines, lineIndex);
        lineIndex = data.getLineIndex();
        o.put(data.getId(), data);
    }
    return o;
}
```

and the caller:

```
weatherData = readData(WeatherData::new, weatherData, "Weather");
```

A `BiFunction` doesn’t mandate how it gets implemented, arbitrary code, like a factory method, could fulfill it, as long as it takes the specified arguments and provides an instance of `T`. The caller can easily specify to use the constructor of a concrete type via `ConcreteType::new`, as shown above. However, now the calling code, i.e. the code containing `WeatherData::new` must have access to the matching constructor; there is no access override possible.

The additional safety is immediately visible, as we now don’t need to catch Reflection related exceptions, whether the constructor exists and is accessible has been checked at compile-time already.

Another advantage of the non-reflective approach is that it even works when `WeatherData` stays an inner class (non-static) of `GameData`, when `WeatherData::new` appears in a non-static context of `GameData`, as the implied parameter will be filled in, just like it would when you write `new WeatherData(dataLines, lineIndex)` at the same code location.